# Поиск по темам форума с низкой нагрузкой на сервер

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, полнотекстовый-поиск

Пользователь вводит строку в поле поиска, нажимает кнопку, после нажатия которой должен отобразиться список тем и сообщений форума с релевантным содержимым. Алгоритм определения релевантности произволен. Критерий оптимизации: максимальная нагрузка должна ложиться на машину клиента. Какие существуют классы алгоритмов, и какой посоветуете реализовать, для решения такой задачи?

Comment: Вспомнилась электронная гадалка из какого-то юморно-фантастического произведения, которая печатала алфавит и примечание: *"Самообслуживание — прогрессивный метод! из этих букв составьте предсказание сами!"* Так что как вариант — держать копии баз данных у клиентов :) Ну, как в FidoNet в свое время, когда все сообщения рассылались всем...

Comment: Публиковать содержимое диалогов, в виде html-страничек. Поиск переадресовывать в google/yandex.  Пусти поиском занимаются их серверы.